# Filter Windows Explorer Directories and Sub Directories for a File name specified within Excel vba

Tags: filter

I want to select and open the file after the filter, It
if I filer for "john"  the result may be

- john.xls
- john.doc
- John.pdf
  I will pick and open the one I want
  Tried various code and searched Google and stack overflow and cannot resolve